# Unable to upload file to SAS URI

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Here I am using Microsoft Storage Library, But I am not able to upload my file to Azure storage

Code:

```
 public class UploadFile {

public static void uploadFile(String sasURL,String filePath,String submissionGuid) throws MalformedURLException, URISyntaxException
{
    URI sasUrl = new URI(sasURL);

    try
    {
        CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(sasUrl);
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(sasUrl.getPath());
        File source = new File(filePath);
        blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source), source.length());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Output the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

Sas Uri Generated is:

```
 https://assetservice.blob.core.windows.net/org66/7594787459-5373-4485-a5ad-8b8a9b5af62c/Input/834793kfhreh-ee2a-4c80-a766-146fc139f2c4.hlkx?sv=2013-08-15&sr=b&sig=jkdhfueiwhdjscnkljshchcvdhcdsnc&se=2016-07-13T18%3A18%3A09Z&sp=w
```

I am getting error message:

```
java.io.IOException
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Utility.initIOException(Utility.java:569)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobOutputStream.writeBlock(BlobOutputStream.java:444)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobOutputStream.access$000(BlobOutputStream.java:53)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobOutputStream$1.call(BlobOutputStream.java:388)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobOutputStream$1.call(BlobOutputStream.java:385)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
```

and authorization error as well, even though sasuri being passed has all the required parameters in it:

```
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:89)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:175)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob.uploadBlockInternal(CloudBlockBlob.java:904)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob.uploadBlock(CloudBlockBlob.java:876)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobOutputStream.writeBlock(BlobOutputStream.java:438)
... 9 more
```

I think I dont understand the part where i should pass Blob-container-name as i even tried passing org66 but it didnt work for me.

I am also confused on the part as in what is my container name etc.

Comment: Are you aware that your SAS has expired two days ago (se=2016-07-13)?

Comment: Yea I am aware of that fact, i randomly changed those numbers just to post it in public domain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per "&sr=b" in your SAS, it's a blob level SAS rather than a container level SAS, you should directly use it to construct your CloudBlockBlob object, not via CloudBlobContainer:

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new URI(sasURL));
File source = new File(filePath);
blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source), source.length());
```

You can find the details on how to correctly use container SAS & blob SAS in this [official documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2/). Though it's based on C#, the code is generally similar.

Comment: I have no errors, But Is there a way I can track the upload status and once its done i can proceed with other set of work?

Comment: In dashboard it still says waitingforupload I am following :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn800660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396                                                                          for driver signing automation for windows 10.and i am stuck on step 4

Answer (score 0):

First, your SAS has expired two days ago (se=2016-07-13).

Second, from the [CloudBlobContainer docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj682564.aspx), **the constructor you use should get the container URI**:

> A Uri object specifying the absolute URI to the container.

If your container is public, you don't need SAS, otherwise - **use SAS URI for the container**, as SAS can be created for specific blobs as well.

Comment: `If your container is public, you don't need SAS` <-- Disagree with this. For some operations (including uploads), you would still need a SAS token even if the container is public.

Comment: I dont understand then what am i suppose to do, I am stuck at this point.

Comment: @MikasaAckerman how did you generate the SAS? your code seems OK, but you may be using a SAS for this specific blob

Comment: Passed authorization token in header with specific json to sysdevendpoint =https://devicesigningservice.cloudapp.net/api/signing/devices url to get sas response